# Remove Days Scroll from Vue Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using Vue Fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue) version 5.10 on my vue project and I am struggling to find a way to remove the scroll at the upper right corner of the calendar. Is this possible?

[image: Vue Fullcalendar Demo]

I am using resourceTimeline view if that helps. Is there a way I can remove/hide the scroll/nav at the upper right? Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: Have you got some CSS which is alerting the text height or the column height?